# Fabric Key For Twitter

Tags: angular, twitter, ionic4, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I have working on one application in ionic 4 and angular 8 and That application is on social media actions handling and display the graph based on likes,posts,engagements,etc for different social media like twitter,facebook,instagram and linkedin and also we can use that application with facebook login , twitter login but the problem is that I have api key and secret key but need fabric key and I can not understand how to create fabric key for twitter login

Can Any One Guide me for that?

Comment: What guide are you currently following? Fabric is now owned by Google and rolled into Firebase https://get.fabric.io/

Answer (score 1):

> use that application with facebook login , twitter login

Fabric is deprecated, and [no longer exists as of March 2020](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap). Those social login features are available with **Firebase**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#next_steps

For Ionic - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication

And Twitter login method - https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication/blob/master/README.md#signinwithtwittertoken-secret

---

I've not used Fabric, but I don't think it provides user engagement data

For example, you'd use a Twitter SDK key to get Profile, Feed and Tweet information

https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient/blob/master/README.md

Comment: But Here we use wihtout firebase social login then how it should be possible for me?I need to add it in twitter plugins in package.json file

Comment: All I can tell you is that Fabric service no longer exists as of March 2020. You can use Firebase or you can implement the OAuth2 process yourself

Comment: All firebase examples I have seen for Ionic still requires you to use the Twitter Connect SDK. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/twitter-connect. The Twitter Connect SDK still required the Fabric Key to install. I don't see wany way for Ionic to do a Twitter login without Fabric Key.

Comment: @Syclone I don't maintain any Ionic or Twitter plugins. You can reach out to this user who does https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin . If using Ionic / Cordova, Firebase should still works on those devices using the link in my answer then going to the Twitter login section

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand your way but when we set plugin for twitter login in package.json It must take fabric key for twitter without that build is not created.

Comment: I can not found how to generate fabric key because in firebase also needs fabric key @Syclone is right. All tutorials displays generated fabric key but not the way to generate it.

Comment: @Dhwani What package are you talking about? The one I linked to has not been updated since 2018

Comment: @Syclone See updated answer for Ionic Firebase Auth, which Github pages show a Twitter login API method

Comment: I am talking about how to generate fabric key for twitter can not find from anything..

Comment: @Dhwani I'll say it again - what package are you trying to use that actually needs it? Please point me to the NPM page. The one Syclone linked is out of date and should be avoided

Comment: @cricket_007 I think what @Dhwani is talking about is the NPM package. When installing the package like so `ionic Cordova plugin add twitter-connect-plugin` or in the package.json with a .npmrc it asks for the FABRIC_KEY. You cannot install the NPM package without that key. The links you provided requires that key still, even though it isn't in the ionic example . If you run the command you will see what we are saying.

Comment: @Syclone Yes., I see that in what you linked, but again, I ask why are you both under the same assumption that you need **that** Twitter package? As I've explained, Twitter login cannot be accompanied by Fabric anymore. Firebase is the alternative, and **does not** require a Fabric key. Just because it's in the Ionic docs doesn't mean that it's "supported" or "currently works"

Comment: @Syclone is right , I have used NPM Package and installing ionic cordova plugin add twitter-connect-plugin and for that I need fabric key for that.

Comment: @cricket_007 Is your meaning that If I used firebase then no need to add plugin for twitter in package.json because I think Fabric key is necessary in plugin.

Comment: @Dhwani 1) You want Twitter login 2) There's more than one option to do so; write your own OAuth2 code, or use an existing library 3) Fabric **used to** be an option. Now you must use `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication` (please see link in my answer, and please follow it to the github page with usage examples). I repeat, it does **not** require a Fabric key, but instead a Firebase API key. I'm not sure if I can make it more clear. Please **remove all fabric dependencies** from your application